How does one free memory in the heap in risc-v assembly?
I am currently studying risc-v assembly and started to research more about the heap. In the current problem I'm solving, I'm creating a linked list by allocating space on the heap with a syscall and saving the data I want and the adrres for the next item.
    li a7, 9
    addi a0, zero, 8
    ecall #aloca 2 espacos iniciais
    
    la s4, ptr #salva o endereço de ptr em s4
    sw a0, 0(s4) #salva o espaço alocado
    
    addi s2, zero, 0 #cont = 0
    add s0, s3, zero #condição de parada
    
loop:
    li a7, 5
    ecall #scan entrada num
    
    add s1, a0, zero #salva a entrada
    
    li a7, 9
    addi a0, zero, 8
    ecall #aloca 2 espaços e retorna em a0

When I'm done with this list I want to deallocate it, but I don't know how, and for what I've researched there is no deallocation syscall, so I don't really know how I would go about freeing this memory.
I didn't try anything beacause I don't have a clue on what to do

What environment are you using? For RARS google says: "There is no deallocation system call. You have the heap memory for the duration of the running program. "
